# Vuetify Select Component Initial Value issue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have vuetify webpack project

In one of my vue components I use v-select with :items set to common array of numbers named 'levels', and v-model set to data property 'level' that holds common number

So the issue is that v-select doesn't show initial value at startup if 'level' is initialized with prop - and shows ok if 'level' is initialized by constant. Smth like this:

```
  props: ['initLevel'],
  data () {
    return {
      levels,
      level: this.initLevel
    }
  }
```

this isn't working correct, but this:

```
...
level: 25
...
```

works fine

v-select usage is:

```
         <v-select
            label="Select Level"
            :items="levels"
            v-model="level"
            max-height="200"
            dense
            autocomplete
          >
        </v-select>
```

Besides initial value showing at startup problem, v-select works fine

So how to solve this problem and what's the reason of it?

Comment: Are you using Vue 2.0 or Vue 1.0?

Comment: @d3L 2.0 cuz `vuetify` doesn't work with vue 1.0 afaik

Comment: no, I use modern vue & vuetify

Comment: but you are getting error w.r.t. mutating props aren't you?

Comment: don't understand what you mean. it looks like data object isn't ready when v-select tries to initialize itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found the problem
it was in types: levels is an array of ints, and prop went as string
standard html select had no problem with it, but v-select had!

Comment: I had the same problem. Turned out the result from my API was a string and my items array had int for values...

Comment: Lifesaver thanx!

Comment: This had me stumped for a while.  I thought I was going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I think `data()` is called before any of the property values are available.

What you can try is moving the initialisation from `data()` to `beforeMount()` like this:

```
props: ['initLevel'],

data() {
    return {
        levels: ...,
        level: 0
    }
},

beforeMount() {
     this.level = this.initLevel
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it's strange but still the same story: if in beforeMount() this.level = 20, then ok, and if this.level = this.initLevel, then v-select has no initial value

Comment: and normal html select initializes fine